# OpenCV GPU Primitives

Tags: opencv, cuda, npp

Are the OpenCV primitives based on the CUDA Nvidia Performance Primitives (NPP)?.

By primitives I mean the same ones implemented in the NPP library, for example: boxFilter, Mirror, Convolution...

I would like to know about this issue as I'm planning use the NPP library. However, OpenCV has more functions that could help me for example in border treatment for image processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV uses NPP library for some functions. But it is hard to create a compelete list of such functions.

Some functions uses only NPP implemetation (`boxFilter`, `graphcut`, `histEven`).

Other functions uses different implemetations for different input parameters. For example, `cv::gpu::resize` uses NPP for some input parameters (`CV_8UC1` and `CV_8UC3` types, `INTER_NEAREST` and `INTER_LINEAR` interpolation mode) and for other parameters it uses own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Great webinar about OpenCV on a GPU using CUDA

Video - http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/opencv.mp4

Slides PDF - http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/webinar/opencv-gtc-express-shalini-gupta.pdf